# How to execute a function in chrome Console using webdriver in python?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools, browser-automation

I have a something like this...

```html
<div style="float:left">
  <input type="button" value="Print" onclick="onPrintClick()" class="buttonStyle">
</div>
```

This is a snipppet from a dynamic webpage.

I'm unable to click this button using *CSS_selector / xpath / id* or in some other ways. It always says "*There is no such element found*". So I want to run  "**onPrintClick()**" in chrome **console** which actually has the same action as clicking the button. So, can  anyone help me regarding this "***clicking the button***" or "***executing the js function i.e. 'onPrintClick()***' in chrome console" in python ?

Thanks.